# Let $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ rational and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ irrational. Prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ rational and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ irrational. Prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I have a vague idea of what I'm supposed to do, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: One way to do it is to show that the upper Riemann sum is at least $1/2$ and the lower Riemann sum is $0$ for any given partition on $[0,1]$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: Are you wanting to show it from first principles? (Because we don't know what all theorems are at your disposal...) If so, one plan is to show that the difference between the upper and lower sums doesn't tend to zero [as outlined here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/the-riemann-integrability-of-a-function-similar-to-dirichlets-function).

Comment: Note a similar function, but where for rational arguments it has $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \frac{1}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive, relatively prime integers, is sometimes called the "Ruler Function", due to its roughly similar appearance to rulers. It is a special case of "Thomae's function", with more info at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Answer (score 3):

Can you prove that $$\overline{\int_0^1}f=\int_0^1 xdx=\frac 1 2$$ and that  $$\underline{\int_0^1}f=0\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

First, show that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere on that interval. Therefore, the set of discontinuities of $f$ is $(0,1]$, and we know

$$ m((0,1]) =  1 - 0 = 1 > 0 $$.

Therefore, $f$ cannot be riemman integrable.

Comment: A little correction: $f$ is discontinuous _except_ at the point $0$ for $x_n\to0$ in $[0,1]\implies$ for $\epsilon>0~\exists~k\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that $|x_n|<0~\forall~n\ge k\implies |f(x_n)|<\epsilon~\forall~n\ge k.$

Comment: @AtahualpaInca What is the $m((0,1])$ mean? Specifically the $m$ part?

Comment: $m$ is the lebesgue measure