# Prove that the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=-x$ if $x$ is irrational, is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: riemann-integration

**Prove that $f(x)=\begin{cases}x  & \text{ if $x$ is rational }  \\    -x & \text{ if $x$ is irrational}   \end{cases}$ is not Riemann integrable on [0,1]**
I'm trying to workout the upper integral and the lower integral. And to say that they are not equal. But got stuck in between.
Definitions that I have been using:
$\bar{I}(f,P)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(a_{j+1}-a_j)\sup\left \{f(x)|a_j\leq x\leq a_{j+1} \right \}$
$\underline{I}(f,P)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(a_{j+1}-a_j)\inf\left \{f(x)|a_j\leq x\leq a_{j+1} \right \}$

$\overline{\int_{0}^{1}}f dx= \underset{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\sup\left \{ \overline{I}(f,P)| P\text{ is a partition on [0,1] with a mesh size}\leq\epsilon \right \}$
$\underline{\int_{0}^{1}}f dx= \underset{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\sup\left \{ \underline{I}(f,P)| P\text{ is a partition on [0,1] with a mesh size}\leq\epsilon \right \}$

Comment: What have you tried? In every interval of size $\epsilon$ there are contained both - irrational and rational numbers.

Comment: The function is continuous in $0$ only, so the function can't be Riemannintegrable by Lebesgue's integral criterion (if you are familiar with that).

Comment: Almost a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596321/let-fx-x-for-x-in0-1-rational-and-fx-0-for-x-in0-1-irrational-p?rq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ are dense. In each Interval $[a_j,a_{j+1}]$ we have $\sup\{f(x):x \in [a_j,a_{j+1}]\}= a_{j+1}$ and $\inf\{f(x):x \in [a_j,a_{j+1}]\}= -a_{j+1}$ Therefore

$\overline{\int_{0}^{t}}f dx=t^2/2$,

$\underline{\int_{0}^{t}}fdx=-t^2/2$

Lets assume we want to calculate $\overline{\int_{0}^{t}}f (x) dx$. We take the partition $Z_n=[0,\frac{t}{n},\frac{2t}{n},...,t]$. Note that if $a_j$ denotes the j.th term in the partition then $a_{j+1}-a_{j}=t/n$ and $ t/n\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$.
Since the supremum of $f$ on each interval is $a_{j+1}=t(j+1)/n$ the integral equals $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (t/n) \frac{t(j+1)}{n}=t^2/2.$

Comment: Could you please let me know your calculation for one of the integrals

Comment: Thank you! it works

Answer (score 1):

The upper integral is $1$ and the lower is $-1$. All you need to observe is that every non-degenerate interval contains a rational number and also an irrational number.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is when we get the suprimum on $(a_j,a_{j+1})$ it gives $a_{j+1}$ but not 1.
And also for the infimum it gives $-a_{j+1}$.
So could you please explain

Comment: I do not understand your concerns.

Comment: The issue with my approach is that I can show that the upper integral is less than or equal to 1 but not the equality (And vice versa )

Comment: That is exactly the point of my answer, please try to understand its details.